# Azure DevOps API Patch call

Tags: azure-devops

I am migrating my JIRA projects to Azure Devops and I wrote a python script to fix the missing links.

Until day before yesterday the script was working fine with PATCH and today(as i tested it) it is failing with 401 error.

I am using PAT to call API's. PAT is working with GET and POST calls but fails with PATCH call. The same PAT was working earlier and it is not expired.

I tried with a new PAT with full scope and limited scope(work ites - read, write and manage)(base64 encoded)

my patch JSON which was working until earlier this week is below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#update-a-field

```
[
    {
      "op": "test",
      "path": "/rev",
      "value": 81
    },
    {
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/relations/-",
      "value": {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Related",
        "url": "<Link URL>",
        "attributes": {
          "comment": "Making a new link for the dependency"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Any thoughts on why it is failing now or anyone facing similar issue recently?

error message:

`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000} outward`

Submit a PATCH call and i expect the work item to get updated.

Comment: It's telling you the problem: You are not authorized to access that REST method. Either your PAT expired or something happened to restrict your access. Please update your question with the steps you've taken to troubleshoot your access.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Figured out the issue is with headers. i was combining two headers in a wrong way

I have

```
{
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization,
}
```

For patch i need this additional one

```
{
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8'
}
```

I was doing append on both headers to build one header which was causing the issue and i fixed the append as below and now my patch calls are working as expected.

patch_headers = headers | additional_headers